# How to test is user is one of the groups in a list of groups

Tags: django, django-permissions

I have a list of groups, and I want to test if the user belongs to any one of the groups.

I can get a list of user's groups:

```
user_groups = user_object.groups.all()
```

And I can use sets:

```
if not set(user_object.groups.all()).isdisjoint(group_list):
```

Is this the best way?

---

Added:

`group_list` comes from a many-to-many field from another model (`MyClass.groups_allowed.all()`)

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    ...
    groups_allowed = ManyToManyField(Group, default=None, blank=True)
    ...

    def user_can_view(self, user_object):
        ...
        if not set(user_object.groups.all()).isdisjoint(self.groups_allowed.all()):
            return True
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check user's group like

```
if user_object.groups.filter(name = groupname).exists():
    pass
```

or

```
if user_object.groups.filter(name__in= groupname_list):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

if `group_list` is queryset:

```
user_object.groups.filter(id__in=group_list.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

else you have get id from that list and do next:

```
user_object.groups.filter(id__in=groups_id_list)
```

it does just one request to your db